# Que tipo arquivo devo usar para armazenar os dados em python

Tags: python-3.x, arquivo, armazenamento

Eu estou criando um programa em Python que necessita armazenar algumas configurações e também precisa salvar os dados em um arquivo próprio (Como o AutoCAD que gera arquivos no formato .DWG). Até agora eu utilizei um banco de dados para as duas situações (Coloquei um banco de dados dentro de um arquivo .ZIP porque preciso armazenar algumas imagens também).

Mas eu não sei se essa é a melhor opção, até porque existem várias outras (.INI, .XML, .JSON, etc...). Então, qual é a melhor opção?

Edit:

Além de armazenar as configurações eu também preciso armazenar alguns dados em uma extensão própria (meu_arquivo.banana por exemplo) como quando você criar um documento no Word, ele ira criar um arquivo .DOCX, que apenas o WORD consegue ler. Também quero saber como armazenar os dados nesse caso (também preciso armazenar imagens nesse caso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o armazenamento de configurações, pode utilizar a extensão .conf e .ini utilizando a lib ConfigParser.

Caso precise salvar dados da aplicação e imagens.
Pode utilizar o banco de dados SQLITE, ele é um banco de dados de arquivo local onde o responsável por fazer o papel de SGBD são as proprias lib's do python.

Para fazer o armazenamento de imagens, o mais indicado seria um repositório próprio para isso pois se trata de dados pesados para um banco, porem, caso deseje realizar tal feito, pode transformar sua imagem em base64 e salvar o string resultante em um campo de blob do banco, e realizar a desconversão quando necessário.

Caso venha utilizar o SQLITE, oriento a utilizar via ORM para facilitar a sua manipulação,  uma excelente biblioteca para isso seria a SQLAlchemy.